# iPhone : Getting a value back from views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

From the view A I open the View B which contains categories in a uitableview, when I select a category I open the view C which contains subcategories for the category (using the CoreData persistence ) in a uitableview, when I select a subcategory I open the view D which contains all my product (using the CoreData persistence ), when I select the the product, how can I set the value into the view A? Avoiding leaks of course...

A(MainWindow)->B(UITableView with category)->C(UITableView with subcategory)->D(UITableView with products)
D->C(with the selected product)->B(with the selected product)->A(with the selected product)

I hope I'm enough understable :D

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller to push/pop?

Comment: Yes, I supposed when the user select the product on the view D, the pop should be done in cascade

Comment: Do you have a single view controller managing all these, or a parent controller that you are subclassing?

Comment: Hem... I call every view like this:
ViewA *a = [[ViewA alloc] initWithNib...];
[self.navigationController pushView..:a];
[a release];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach assumes you are using an `UINavigationController` with a stack of `UIViewController` instances, each of which having a managed object context instance as a part of a Core Data application.

Set up an `ivar` and a `@property` in your application delegate header that holds a value for the selected product (an `NSManagedObjectID*`, for example):

```
NSManagedObjectID *selectedProduct;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectID *selectedProduct;
```

Synthesize this `ivar` in the implementation, and release it in `-dealloc`:

```
@synthesize selectedProduct;
...
- (void) dealloc {
    [selectedProduct release], selectedProduct = nil;
    ...
}
```

Set up the following macro wherever you keep your constants, or in each view controller header:

```
#define UIAppDelegate ((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

From any view controller, thereafter, you will be able to set and access your `selectedProduct` value, e.g.:

```
NSManagedObject *foo;

// set the property
[UIAppDelegate setSelectedProduct:[foo objectID]]; 

// access the property
foo = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:[UIAppDelegate selectedProduct]];
```

You don't necessarily have to use an `NSManagedObjectID*` here. You can use any class you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two resources with information related to your question:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7849-passing-data-back-root-view-controller.html

[iPhone SDK - pass data from AppDelegate to a rootviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495929/iphone-sdk-pass-data-from-appdelegate-to-a-rootviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass the pointer to viewA down to viewD through all the other view(controllers ?)

```
// e.g inside ViewB
...
ViewC *viewC = [[ViewC alloc] initWithFrame: myFrame andMainView: viewA];


// inside ViewD finally
...
[viewA setProductImageWithID: self.selctedProduct.id];
```

Another way might be making viewA a singleton and instantiating it anywhere you need to use it. There are good examples on Obj-C singletons here on SO.

Take care,
marius

ps.: hope I got your problem not completely wrong ;)

Comment: I tried this with "delegate"
B has for delegate A, C has for delegate B, D has for delegate C
when the user selected the product I tried from D [delegate setProduct:theProduct] and so on...
however I get an BAD_ACCESS when the views are being released